# I have a HashTable that I would like to create an ArrayLIst, for each key

Tags: javascript, java, regex, arraylist

I have a hashtable. Inside I've added keys, and values. But now I need to have an arrayList for each keyvalue. I was thinking I needed to create an ArrayList with the ArrayList name from the hashtable key and the contents of the hashtable values placed inside values. I'm using Ultra-Studio to make modifications to this script file.
So for instance in my hashtable
This will be the name of the ArrayList: SW_Version
Second all SW Version values will be added SW_Version
I think what I need to do is first cycle through the hashtable gather all the SW Versions values and put them in
I'm very confused on this, please be patient with me. I have to write my JAVA code in an javaScript file

I wanted to pull data directly from the hashTable, I would also need to group the keys and add the values into the arrayList.

Here are my Hashtable and ArrayList declaration.

```
   var legendRows = newPackages.java.util.ArrayList();
   var xmlItems = newPackages.java.util.ArrayList();
   var modeItems = newPackages.java.util.ArrayList();
   var ircDOORSHashTable = newjava.util.Hashtable();
```

This is my code:

This function gets the "Legacy Data" value from a procedure bean. It then adds the table cell values into the HashTable "ircDOORSHashTable".

- Cell key = var mapKeyDOORS
- Cell value = mapKeyDOORSValue

  ```
     function getDOORSData(documentID, contentBean, text) {
    var xmlText = cleanTable(text);
    try
    {
        var docFactory = Packages.javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        var docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        var sbis = newPackages.org.xml.sax.InputSource(newjava.io.StringReader(xmlText));
        var document = docBuilder.parse(sbis);
        var root = document.getDocumentElement();
        varnodeList = root.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (row = 0; row < nodeList.getLength(); row++) {
            var node = nodeList.item(row);
            var mapKeyDOORS = newjava.lang.String(node.getElementsByTagName("td").item(0).getTextContent().trim());
            var mapKeyDOORSValue = newjava.lang.String(node.getElementsByTagName("td").item(1).getTextContent().trim());
            if((mapKeyDOORS !== null && mapKeyDOORS!=="") && (mapKeyDOORSValue!== null || mapKeyDOORSValue !== "")){
                // Returnsanarrayoflineitems.
                varibplValues = parseFields(mapKeyDOORSValue);

                for (varf = 0; f < ibplValues.length; f++) {
                    log("InsidegetDOORSDatafunction. InfirstPass")
                    checkIBPL(ibplValues[f], documentID, contentBean, mapKeyDOORS);
                }else{
                    log("ArrayList xmlItem: " + ibplValues[i]);
                    xmlItems.add(ibplValues[f]);
                    ircDOORSHashTable.put(mapKeyDOORS, ibplValues[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  ```

  }catch(e){
  log ("ErrorfoundingetDOORSDatafunction " + e);
  }
  }

Thankyou, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: “I have to write my JAVA code in an javaScript file” — Why? That seems bizarre.

Comment: “Multimap” is the technical term for a map where each key leads to multiple values rather than a single value. Search Stack Overflow to find much coverage on the topic.

Comment: By the way, `Hashtable` is legacy. Read [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Hashtable.html) where it recommends the use of modern classes instead.

Comment: Thank you I'll look into mulimap and read up on Hashtables

Comment: You’ll find discussions of third-party [multimap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) implementations found in libraries such as *Google Guava* and *Eclipse Collections*. And now modern Java offers syntax to manage a `List` or `Set` as the value of a map.

Comment: Yes I agree a stream of consciousness. I'll rewrite it

Comment: And see [ask], please